# Which came first, the A-0 system or Short Code?

Tags: compiler-construction

I have read in many places that the A-0 system compiler came first, but I found a book "A History of Computing in the Twentieth Century" and it stated that William Schmitt implemented short code in 1949. I had always heard that Grace Hopper was the first person to write a compiler, but this was in 1952. So which came first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like [Short Code came first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Code_(computer_language)), but it was closer to an interpreter than a compiler. The [A-0 System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-0_System) was introduced about a year later and is closer to a modern compiler than Short Code.

Comment: Thanks very much you wouldn't believe how long its taken me to find an answer for this.